# How to update access permission for existing folders in Google

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In Google Drive, I have 100 folders that contains 4 documents in each. Each user who has access to these folders has 'can edit' permissions. I would like to update it to 'can view' for the folder and files within it using Google Script.

I've tried the following codes:

```
function codeone() {
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("fsdfdsfsdfsfsf");
folder.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
}


function codetwo() {
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("12345677989809");
    folder.removeEditor('emailaddress@test.com');
    folder.addViewer('emailaddress@test.com');
}
```

Codeone runs with no issues but does not update the permissions from 'can edit' to 'can view'.

Codetwo updates the folder permission to 'can view' but the files within it still remain as 'can edit'.

Help!

Comment: Get files and ``removeEditor``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function removeAllEditotrs(){
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  var folder, files, file, folderEditors, fileEditors;

  while(folders.hasNext()){
    folder = folders.next();
    folderEditors = folder.getEditors();
    files = folder.getFiles();

    while(files.hasNext()){
      file = files.next();
      fileEditors = file.getEditors();
      for (var i = 0; i < fileEditors.length; i++){
        file.removeEditor(fileEditors[i]);
        file.addViewer(fileEditors[i]); // When removing editors from a file it also removes them as viewers, so I'm adding them again.
        Logger.log("Removed editor " + fileEditors[i].getEmail() + " from file " + file.getName() + " and added them as a viewer.");
      }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < folderEditors.length; i++){
      folder.removeEditor(folderEditors[i]);
      Logger.log("Removed editor " + folderEditors[i].getEmail() + " from folder " + folder.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

This will remove all editors from all folders and files, and add the former editors as viewers of the files.

- [`getFolders()` documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolders)
- [1removeEditor() documentation`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#removeeditoruser)
- [addViewer() documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#addvieweruser)

Comment: You're a genius. That works perfectly. THANK YOU! @AMolina

Comment: One more question, how do I stop the notification that they've been 'Invited to view' the file they've been added to? @Amolina

Comment: There is a way, as outlined [in this article](https://ctrlq.org/code/20101-share-files-google-drive-without-email-notifications) it would basically mean witching the `addviewer()` method for the `Drive.Permissions.insert()` one, including the parameter of not having permissions. This is a Google Advanced Service, and it would need to be enabled as specified [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).